# Using cloud task and cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I'm trying here to use cloud task with cloud function, so that when a field of my collection is set to true, a task will set it automatically to false after 24 hours.
But i don't understand well everythings about using cloud task and cloud functions so i really need some help...

How i can get the value of the userId of the Trigger onUpdate Cloud function to be send into the Http cloud functions, so that i can use it, to update the specific field, which is a map ?

Here my functions :

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
const { CloudTasksClient } = require('@google-cloud/tasks');

admin.initializeApp()
    exports.onUpdateSavedPostsReUpdateItLater = functions.firestore
      .document("/saved/{userId}/savedPosts/{postId}")
      .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
        const userId = context.params.userId;
        const postUpdate = change.after.data();
        const pStatus = postUpdate.prayers[userId]; // The field that i want to update


        updateAtSeconds = Date.now() / 1000 + 86400; //86400 equal to 24 hours, because i want my documents to be updated in the next 24 hours


        // Get the project ID from the FIREBASE_CONFIG env var
        const project = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG!).projectId;
        const location = 'europe-west3';
        const queue = 'ijn-amen';

        const tasksClient = new CloudTasksClient();
        const queuePath: string =
          tasksClient.queuePath(project, location, queue);


        const url = 'https://${location}-${project}.cloudfunctions.net/firestoreTtlCallback';
        const docPath = change.ref.path;
        const payload: UpdateTaskPayload = { docPath };

        const task = {
          httpRequest: {
            httpMethod: 'POST',
            url,
            body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString('base64'),
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          },
          scheduleTime: {
            seconds: updateAtSeconds
          }
        };

        const [response] = await tasksClient.createTask({ parent: queuePath, task });

        console.log('Created task ${response.name}');
      });



    export const firestoreTtlCallback =
      functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
        const payload = req.body as UpdateTaskPayload
        try {
          await admin.firestore().doc(payload.docPath).update({ 'prayers.${userId}': false });
          res.send(200);
        }
        catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          res.status(500).send(error);
        }
      });
```

Thank you,

Comment: It looks like you're already doing that: `const userId = context.params.userId`

Comment: @DougStevenson Yea but how i can manage to use it in the firestoreTtlCallBack, because if i'm right, it's there that update will be made.When using cloud task and cloud functions together the  scheduled action is made in the Http functions right ?

Comment: Sure, you can use a cloud functions trigger to create a task that invokes another trigger.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yea i know but i what i want to know is how i can get the another trigger which here is firestoreTtlCallBack, to get the userId from the first trigger ? Because if you didn't see, i want to update a specific field from a specific doc .

Comment: Put it in the payload of the task?

Comment: @DougStevenson The things is i need both the docPath and the userId, can i put both in the payload of the task ? and if yes, how i can do that ?

Comment: Sure, just build the payload object the way you want.  This is basic JavaScript.